# two way data binding on select ngModel in Angular 5 when ngValue is object

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am using `[(ngModel)]` as a whole object. And this works fine when I do from scratch, but not when I use it in edit mode. So when, for example when I assign the `ngModel` via some other function, the select dropdown's view doesn't update. 
Here's how my HTML looks.

```
<select 
  class="form-control" 
  [(ngModel)]="selectedContentType" 
  [attr.disabled]="hideCollectionandContentType || hideContentTypeOnly ? '' : null" 
  required 
  (change)="contentTypeChanged(selectedContentType)">
  <option [ngValue]="undefined">
    Select Content Type
  </option>
  <option 
    *ngFor="let c of contentTypes" 
    [ngValue]="c">
    {{c.value}}
  </option>
</select>
```

The json for contentTypes looks like this format for each object.

```
{ key: '', value: ''}
```

For example, I am reading an existing form, which is supposed to display data coming from an API. I am setting the data back like this.

```
const selectedContentType = JSON.parse(res.BulkUpdate_SelectedContentType);
        this.selectedContentType = { key: selectedContentType.ContentTypeId, value: selectedContentType.ContentTypeName };
```

Its setting in the right format, but the select dropdown is not updating.

Comment: Can you post some of your TS code explaining how you are trying to set he values?

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari added

Answer (score 1):

if you want to set the dropdown you have to set same object reference,object in javascript compare by reference and when you set `selectedContentType` to new object even if it 's has the same property and value it 's  consider a different value.

this is a new object reference and it 's not eqale to any option value.

```
  this.selectedContentType = { key: selectedContentType.ContentTypeId, value: selectedContentType.ContentTypeName };
```

*example*

```
contentTypes = [
    {name:1,value:1},
    {name:2,value:2},
    {name:3,value:3},
    {name:4,value:4},
    ];

set() {
      // this.selectedContentType = {name:1,value:1}; // not working , new object refrences
      this.selectedContentType = this.contentTypes[0]; 
    }
```

if you want to set the selected item to value of 4 as an example

```
this.selectedContentType = this.contentTypes.find(i => i.value == 4);
```

in the line above we get the same object reference in the dropdown option list.

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dropdown-ngvalue)